# Why does this R function not short-circuit properly?

Tags: r

I'm working my way through the Data Science courses at DataCamp. (Not a plug.) One of the practice lessons has the following completed solution:

```
# logs is available in your workspace

extract_info <- function(x, property = "success", include_all = TRUE) {
  info <- c()
  for (log in x) {

    if (include_all || !log$success) {
      info <- c(info, log[[property]])
    }

  }
  return(info)
}

# Call extract_info() on logs, no additional arguments
extract_info(logs)

# Call extract_info() on logs, set include_all to FALSE
extract_info(logs, include_all = FALSE)
```

The first call (`extract_info(logs)`) works as I would expect it to: it returns a vector containing all the log entries (regardless of the value of `log$success`).

The second call (`extract_info(logs, include_all = FALSE)`) does not return the results I would expect. It returns a vector containing only those results where `log$success` evaluates to `FALSE`.

It seems to me that the use of the `||` operator should cause the if block to short-circuit, and the second call should return *nothing*. From what I can tell, R evaluates expressions from left to right; but this looks like it's evaluating from right to left.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

(According to the site, this is the correct solution, and there's nothing wrong with the code. I want to know why it works the way it does. Even if the answer is that I'm overlooking something painfully obvious and stupid.)

Comment: || is OR.  If either condition is TRUE, it evaluates to TRUE,  so just because include_all is FALSE does not mean it should stop. Are you thinking about AND?

Comment: I'm having a serious mental breakdown here. This is what I get for studying all weekend. It's not if any of them are false, bail. It's if any of them are TRUE, execute. Can you please put that in an answer for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this was a temporary confusion.

|| is OR and so if either condition evaluates to TRUE, the compound expression evaluates to TRUE.  If include_all was TRUE,  you could short-circuit the expression,  but when include_all is FALSE,  you must wait to see what the other part is.

Answer (score 4):

Well `||` is the "or" operator. You don't short circuit the "or" operator with a  FALSE value; you basically ignore that parameter and just look at the next one because you are looking for any TRUE value.

Assume `a` is a boolean value. These should be equivalent (`<==>`).

```
# or
FALSE || a <==> a
TRUE || a <==> TRUE
# and
TRUE && a <==> a
FALSE && a <==> FALSE
```